# Samba and Windows 7: How to update client login

Tags: windows, samba

Have the machine list in the network. Changed a user, adding them to a group to give write permissions on a directory.
User still cannot make changes in directory, probably because the winows client is still logged in.
Is there a way to log the user out of the Samba connection without rebooting the machines? That seems a bit drastic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the windows user could not write to the samba share.
A partial solution was to add that user to the group in question.
The other part of the solution was to add

```
writable = yes
```

to the smb.conf and restart samba, which immediately gave write access to the user.

The solution was not in the reboot.